# Performing POST Request Using Chilkat Not Working Anymore While Was Working Just Few Days Ago

Tags: http, post, chilkat

all was working fine, i was sending a post request to one of the website, it working very nice till now. but all at a sudden it has stopped working..

here is the verbose log of the request:

```
<ChilkatLog>
  <SynchronousRequest ms="65172">
    <DllDate>Mar 28 2023</DllDate>
    <ChilkatVersion>9.5.0.94</ChilkatVersion>
    <Architecture>Little Endian; 32-bit</Architecture>
    <Language>.NET 4.8 / x86</Language>
    <VerboseLogging>1</VerboseLogging>
    <domain>www.ups.com</domain>
    <port>443</port>
    <ssl>True</ssl>
    <httpRequest>
      <httpVersion>1.1</httpVersion>
      <verb>POST</verb>
      <path>/track/api/Track/GetStatus</path>
      <contentType>application/json</contentType>
      <charset>utf-8</charset>
      <sendCharset>1</sendCharset>
      <mimeHeader><![CDATA[User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0
Accept: application/json
Referer: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/
X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8Jcj9...DzspkOLwVamXGvlLlb4]]></mimeHeader>
      <requestItems>
        <requestItem>
          <paramName>loc</paramName>
          <paramValue>en_US</paramValue>
        </requestItem>
      </requestItems>
    </httpRequest>
    <readTimeout>30</readTimeout>
    <connectTimeout>30</connectTimeout>
    <computeApproxRequestDataSize>
      <info>Request body is in a memory buffer..</info>
      <bodySize>58</bodySize>
    </computeApproxRequestDataSize>
    <approxRequestSize>58</approxRequestSize>
    <fullRequest ms="65172">
      <httpRequest>
        <httpVersion>1.1</httpVersion>
        <verb>POST</verb>
        <path>/track/api/Track/GetStatus</path>
        <contentType>application/json</contentType>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <sendCharset>1</sendCharset>
        <mimeHeader><![CDATA[User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0
Accept: application/json
Referer: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/
X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8Jcj9...DzspkOLwVamXGvlLlb4]]></mimeHeader>
        <requestItems>
          <requestItem>
            <paramName>loc</paramName>
            <paramValue>en_US</paramValue>
          </requestItem>
        </requestItems>
      </httpRequest>
      <HttpOptions>
        <AddHostHeader>1</AddHostHeader>
        <AllowCookieResponseCaching>0</AllowCookieResponseCaching>
        <AllowGzip>1</AllowGzip>
        <CookieDir>memory</CookieDir>
        <FollowRedirects>1</FollowRedirects>
        <Login></Login>
        <LoginDomain></LoginDomain>
        <AuthMethod></AuthMethod>
        <MaxResponseSize>0</MaxResponseSize>
        <MaxUrlLen>2000</MaxUrlLen>
        <ReadTimeoutMs>30000</ReadTimeoutMs>
        <RequiredContentType></RequiredContentType>
        <ResumePoint>0</ResumePoint>
        <SaveCookies>1</SaveCookies>
        <SendCookies>1</SendCookies>
        <UnavailableRetryCount>0</UnavailableRetryCount>
        <UnavailableRetryWaitMs>2000</UnavailableRetryWaitMs>
      </HttpOptions>
      <findAddHttpConn>
        <sbHostname0>www.ups.com</sbHostname0>
        <port>443</port>
        <bTls>True</bTls>
        <bForceNewConnection>False</bForceNewConnection>
        <sbProxyDomain>91.205.105.126</sbProxyDomain>
        <proxyPort>3199</proxyPort>
        <numExistingConnections>1</numExistingConnections>
        <lookingForHost>[www.ups.com]</lookingForHost>
        <lookingForPort>443</lookingForPort>
        <lookingForProxy>[91.205.105.126]</lookingForProxy>
        <existingConnection>
          <connection>[www.ups.com]</connection>
          <port>443</port>
          <connection_proxyHost>[91.205.105.126]</connection_proxyHost>
          <proxyPort>3199</proxyPort>
          <info>Found existing proxy connection.</info>
        </existingConnection>
      </findAddHttpConn>
      <a_synchronousRequest ms="31750">
        <generateRequestHeader>
          <sbHost0>www.ups.com</sbHost0>
          <httpRequestGenStartLine>
            <authOnly>0</authOnly>
            <hasMimeBody>1</hasMimeBody>
            <genStartLine>
              <info>Adding params to the start line...</info>
              <startLine>POST /track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US HTTP/1.1</startLine>
            </genStartLine>
          </httpRequestGenStartLine>
          <startLine><![CDATA[POST /track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US HTTP/1.1
]]></startLine>
          <addHostHeader>www.ups.com</addHostHeader>
          <addCookies>
            <info>Auto-adding any accumulated cookies.</info>
            <CookieDir>memory</CookieDir>
            <CookieDomain>www.ups.com</CookieDomain>
            <CookiePath>/track/api/Track/GetStatus</CookiePath>
            <loadCookieJar>
              <Path>/track/api/Track/GetStatus</Path>
              <GetDomainCookiesXml>
                <CookieDir>memory</CookieDir>
                <Domain>www.ups.com</Domain>
                <HashKey>ups_com.xml</HashKey>
              </GetDomainCookiesXml>
            </loadCookieJar>
            <AddingCookie>X-CSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8Jcj9GhlwkdBikuRYz....3224885</AddingCookie>
          </addCookies>
          <genContentTypeHdrLine>
            <requestCharset>utf-8</requestCharset>
          </genContentTypeHdrLine>
          <genHeaderSb>
            <getMimeHeaderHttp3>
              <headerField>X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8Jcj9GhlwkdBikuRYzfhrpLnUtfoDjZ9zJbnBa2cdI7u99GXqf2msAc0oHX0hj8mRl8IUWEk-3vHjtelXX3l1GlQ4WPbLsFErdeIu4EcfHEu8pyHkZ-tUyfe-0Q-Qf_TO8U-DzspkOLwVamXGvlLlb4</headerField>
            </getMimeHeaderHttp3>
          </genHeaderSb>
          <finalRequestHdr><![CDATA[Host: www.ups.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0
Accept: application/json
Referer: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 58
Cookie: X-CSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8Jcj9...4277296~3224885
X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8Jcj...DzspkOLwVamXGvlLlb4

]]></finalRequestHdr>
        </generateRequestHeader>
        <fullHttpRequest ms="31750">
          <domain>www.ups.com</domain>
          <port>443</port>
          <ssl>True</ssl>
          <openHttpConnection>
            <info>Using existing connection.</info>
          </openHttpConnection>
          <connectTime>Elapsed time: 0 millisec</connectTime>
          <startLine>POST /track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US HTTP/1.1</startLine>
          <fullRequestHeader>
            <requestHeader><![CDATA[Host: www.ups.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0
Accept: application/json
Referer: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 58
Cookie: X-CSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8Jcj9...7NoNQE+n1U/TY=~4277296~3224885
X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8Jcj9...DzspkOLwVamXGvlLlb4]]></requestHeader>
          </fullRequestHeader>
          <computeApproxRequestDataSize>
            <info>Request body is in a memory buffer..</info>
            <bodySize>58</bodySize>
          </computeApproxRequestDataSize>
          <sendRequestHeader>
            <sendHeaderElapsedMs>0</sendHeaderElapsedMs>
          </sendRequestHeader>
          <sendRequestBody>
            <idleTimeoutMs>30000</idleTimeoutMs>
            <rqdType>4</rqdType>
            <sendBodyElapsedMs>0</sendBodyElapsedMs>
          </sendRequestBody>
          <readResponseHeader ms="31734">
            <error>The server did not respond in 30000 milliseconds.</error>
            <error>Try increasing the value of your Http.ReadTimeout property.</error>
            <quickCloseHttpConnection ms="281">
              <shutdownChannel ms="281">
                <info>(bForceClose) socket shutdown..</info>
                <terminateConnection ms="281">
                  <info>TCP connection cleanly closed by peer.</info>
                  <info>Cleanly terminated TCP connection.</info>
                </terminateConnection>
                <info>Clearing TLS client certificates.</info>
              </shutdownChannel>
            </quickCloseHttpConnection>
          </readResponseHeader>
        </fullHttpRequest>
        <success>0</success>
      </a_synchronousRequest>
      <retryAfterLostConnectionDiscovered2 ms="33422">
        <findAddHttpConn>
          <sbHostname0>www.ups.com</sbHostname0>
          <port>443</port>
          <bTls>True</bTls>
          <bForceNewConnection>True</bForceNewConnection>
          <sbProxyDomain>91.205.105.126</sbProxyDomain>
          <proxyPort>3199</proxyPort>
          <numExistingConnections>1</numExistingConnections>
          <lookingForHost>[www.ups.com]</lookingForHost>
          <lookingForPort>443</lookingForPort>
          <lookingForProxy>[91.205.105.126]</lookingForProxy>
          <existingConnection>
            <connection>[]</connection>
            <port>443</port>
            <connection_proxyHost>[91.205.105.126]</connection_proxyHost>
            <proxyPort>3199</proxyPort>
          </existingConnection>
          <info>Will need to open a new connection.</info>
        </findAddHttpConn>
        <a_synchronousRequest ms="33422">
          <generateRequestHeader>
            <sbHost0>www.ups.com</sbHost0>
            <httpRequestGenStartLine>
              <authOnly>0</authOnly>
              <hasMimeBody>1</hasMimeBody>
              <genStartLine>
                <info>Adding params to the start line...</info>
                <startLine>POST /track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US HTTP/1.1</startLine>
              </genStartLine>
            </httpRequestGenStartLine>
            <startLine><![CDATA[POST /track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US HTTP/1.1
]]></startLine>
            <addHostHeader>www.ups.com</addHostHeader>
            <addCookies>
              <info>Auto-adding any accumulated cookies.</info>
              <CookieDir>memory</CookieDir>
              <CookieDomain>www.ups.com</CookieDomain>
              <CookiePath>/track/api/Track/GetStatus</CookiePath>
              <loadCookieJar>
                <Path>/track/api/Track/GetStatus</Path>
                <GetDomainCookiesXml>
                  <CookieDir>memory</CookieDir>
                  <Domain>www.ups.com</Domain>
                  <HashKey>ups_com.xml</HashKey>
                </GetDomainCookiesXml>
              </loadCookieJar>
              <AddingCookie>X-CSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8Jcj...3224885</AddingCookie>
            </addCookies>
            <genContentTypeHdrLine>
              <requestCharset>utf-8</requestCharset>
            </genContentTypeHdrLine>
            <genHeaderSb>
              <getMimeHeaderHttp3>
                <headerField>X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfD..VamXGvlLlb4</headerField>
              </getMimeHeaderHttp3>
            </genHeaderSb>
            <finalRequestHdr><![CDATA[Host: www.ups.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0
Accept: application/json
Referer: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 58
Cookie: X-CSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8Jcj9Ghlwkd...4277296~3224885
X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8Jcj...OLwVamXGvlLlb4

]]></finalRequestHdr>
          </generateRequestHeader>
          <fullHttpRequest ms="33422">
            <domain>www.ups.com</domain>
            <port>443</port>
            <ssl>True</ssl>
            <openHttpConnection ms="1360">
              <info>Opening connection through an HTTP proxy.</info>
              <proxyDomain>91.205.105.126</proxyDomain>
              <proxyPort>3199</proxyPort>
              <httpHostname>www.ups.com</httpHostname>
              <httpPort>443</httpPort>
              <tls>True</tls>
              <bUsingHttpProxy>True</bUsingHttpProxy>
              <httpProxyAuthMethod></httpProxyAuthMethod>
              <m_httpProxyTls>False</m_httpProxyTls>
              <info>Using a CONNECT tunnel...</info>
              <socket2Connect ms="1360">
                <info>Using HTTP proxy CONNECT...</info>
                <httpProxyConnect ms="1079">
                  <proxyAuthMethod></proxyAuthMethod>
                  <proxyHostname>91.205.105.126</proxyHostname>
                  <proxyPort>3199</proxyPort>
                  <info>No proxy authentication method specified.</info>
                  <proxyUsername>agneshicks1956-etn2c</proxyUsername>
                  <connectSocket ms="282">
                    <domainOrIpAddress>91.205.105.126</domainOrIpAddress>
                    <port>3199</port>
                    <connectTimeoutMs>30000</connectTimeoutMs>
                    <connect_ipv6_or_ipv4 ms="282">
                      <info>This is an IPV4 numeric address.</info>
                      <info>Domain to IP address resolution not needed.</info>
                      <info>connecting to IPV4 address...</info>
                      <ipAddress>91.205.105.126</ipAddress>
                      <createSocket>
                        <info>Setting SO_SNDBUF size</info>
                        <sendBufSize>262144</sendBufSize>
                        <info>Setting SO_RCVBUF size</info>
                        <recvBufSize>4194304</recvBufSize>
                      </createSocket>
                      <connect ms="282">
                        <info>Waiting for the connect to complete...</info>
                        <connectTimeoutMs>30000</connectTimeoutMs>
                        <myIP>192.168.0.108</myIP>
                        <myPort>51062</myPort>
                        <info>socket connect successful.</info>
                      </connect>
                    </connect_ipv6_or_ipv4>
                  </connectSocket>
                  <connectRequest><![CDATA[CONNECT www.ups.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: www.ups.com:443]]></connectRequest>
                  <connectResponseHeader><![CDATA[HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Server: squid/3.5.23
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 02 Aug 2023 05:38:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3523
X-Squid-Error: ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
Proxy-Authenticate: ****
X-Cache: MISS from StormHa
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from StormHa:3199
Via: 1.1 StormHa (squid/3.5.23)
Connection: keep-alive]]></connectResponseHeader>
                  <contentLength>3523</contentLength>
                  <firstLine>HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required</firstLine>
                  <info>Proxy authentication is required.</info>
                  <proxyResponseHeader><![CDATA[HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Server: squid/3.5.23
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 02 Aug 2023 05:38:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3523
X-Squid-Error: ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
Proxy-Authenticate: ****
X-Cache: MISS from StormHa
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from StormHa:3199
Via: 1.1 StormHa (squid/3.5.23)
Connection: keep-alive]]></proxyResponseHeader>
                  <info>The server supports the Basic proxy authentication method.</info>
                  <info>Re-sending with Basic Authorization header...</info>
                  <connectSocket ms="266">
                    <domainOrIpAddress>91.205.105.126</domainOrIpAddress>
                    <port>3199</port>
                    <connectTimeoutMs>30000</connectTimeoutMs>
                    <connect_ipv6_or_ipv4 ms="266">
                      <info>This is an IPV4 numeric address.</info>
                      <info>Domain to IP address resolution not needed.</info>
                      <info>connecting to IPV4 address...</info>
                      <ipAddress>91.205.105.126</ipAddress>
                      <createSocket>
                        <info>Setting SO_SNDBUF size</info>
                        <sendBufSize>262144</sendBufSize>
                        <info>Setting SO_RCVBUF size</info>
                        <recvBufSize>4194304</recvBufSize>
                      </createSocket>
                      <connect ms="266">
                        <info>Waiting for the connect to complete...</info>
                        <connectTimeoutMs>30000</connectTimeoutMs>
                        <myIP>192.168.0.108</myIP>
                        <myPort>51063</myPort>
                        <info>socket connect successful.</info>
                      </connect>
                    </connect_ipv6_or_ipv4>
                  </connectSocket>
                  <connectRequest><![CDATA[CONNECT www.ups.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Authorization: ****
Host: www.ups.com:443]]></connectRequest>
                  <connectResponseHeader>HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established</connectResponseHeader>
                  <contentLength>0</contentLength>
                  <firstLine>HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established</firstLine>
                  <info>HTTP proxy connect success</info>
                </httpProxyConnect>
                <convertToTls ms="281">
                  <info>Clearing TLS client certificates.</info>
                  <clientHandshake ms="281">
                    <info>The client cert chain is NULL.</info>
                    <cacheClientCerts>
                      <info>Cached TLS client certificates.</info>
                      <info>Client cert chain is NULL.</info>
                    </cacheClientCerts>
                    <clientHandshake2 ms="281">
                      <sendClientHello>
                        <TlsClientHello_buildMessage>
                          <gen_key_shares>
                            <generateNewKey_ecc>
                              <loadCurveByName>
                                <name>secp256r1</name>
                              </loadCurveByName>
                            </generateNewKey_ecc>
                          </gen_key_shares>
                        </TlsClientHello_buildMessage>
                      </sendClientHello>
                      <readHandshakeMessages ms="281">
                        <processHandshakeRecord ms="16">
                          <processHandshakeMessage ms="16">
                            <processServerHello ms="16">
                              <negotiatedTlsVersion>TLS 1.3</negotiatedTlsVersion>
                              <negotiatedCipherSuite>TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384</negotiatedCipherSuite>
                              <minAcceptableRsaKeySize>1024</minAcceptableRsaKeySize>
                            </processServerHello>
                          </processHandshakeMessage>
                        </processHandshakeRecord>
                      </readHandshakeMessages>
                      <tls13ProcessCertificateVerify>
                        <x509_getPublicKey>
                          <info>Returning DSA or ECDSA public key from X.509 cert...</info>
                        </x509_getPublicKey>
                        <loadAnyDer>
                          <loadAnyAsn>
                            <loadAnyEccAsn>
                              <loadEccPublicAsn>
                                <curveOid>1.2.840.10045.3.1.7</curveOid>
                                <loadCurveByOid>
                                  <oid>1.2.840.10045.3.1.7</oid>
                                  <loadCurveByName>
                                    <name>secp256r1</name>
                                  </loadCurveByName>
                                </loadCurveByOid>
                                <dbPubKeySize>66</dbPubKeySize>
                              </loadEccPublicAsn>
                            </loadAnyEccAsn>
                          </loadAnyAsn>
                        </loadAnyDer>
                        <verifyTls13Signature>
                          <eccVerifyHash>
                            <unpackDsaSig>
                              <siglen>72</siglen>
                              <isAsnSig>True</isAsnSig>
                              <sig>3046022100F013F...4D8A82</sig>
                            </unpackDsaSig>
                          </eccVerifyHash>
                        </verifyTls13Signature>
                      </tls13ProcessCertificateVerify>
                    </clientHandshake2>
                  </clientHandshake>
                  <checkServerCert>
                    <info>Not verifying server certificate...</info>
                    <info>Set the RequireSslCertVerify property to enable verification.</info>
                  </checkServerCert>
                  <info>Secure Channel Established.</info>
                </convertToTls>
              </socket2Connect>
              <info>Turning on TCP_NODELAY.</info>
              <socketOptions>
                <SO_SNDBUF>262144</SO_SNDBUF>
                <SO_RCVBUF>4194304</SO_RCVBUF>
                <TCP_NODELAY>1</TCP_NODELAY>
                <SO_KEEPALIVE>1</SO_KEEPALIVE>
              </socketOptions>
              <info>HTTPS secure channel established.</info>
            </openHttpConnection>
            <connectTime>Elapsed time: 1360 millisec</connectTime>
            <startLine>POST /track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US HTTP/1.1</startLine>
            <fullRequestHeader>
              <requestHeader><![CDATA[Host: www.ups.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0
Accept: application/json
Referer: https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 58
Cookie: X-CSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8Jc...TY=~4277296~3224885
X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8Jcj9G...vlLlb4]]></requestHeader>
            </fullRequestHeader>
            <computeApproxRequestDataSize>
              <info>Request body is in a memory buffer..</info>
              <bodySize>58</bodySize>
            </computeApproxRequestDataSize>
            <sendRequestHeader>
              <sendHeaderElapsedMs>0</sendHeaderElapsedMs>
            </sendRequestHeader>
            <sendRequestBody>
              <idleTimeoutMs>30000</idleTimeoutMs>
              <rqdType>4</rqdType>
              <sendBodyElapsedMs>0</sendBodyElapsedMs>
            </sendRequestBody>
            <readResponseHeader ms="32062">
              <processHandshakeRecord>
                <processHandshakeMessage>
                  <processNewSessionTicket>
                    <ticket_lifetime>0x1449c</ticket_lifetime>
                    <ticket_lifetime>83100</ticket_lifetime>
                    <ticket_age_add>0xe2170412</ticket_age_add>
                    <ticket_age_add>3793159186</ticket_age_add>
                    <m_nonce_size>8</m_nonce_size>
                    <ticketLen>224</ticketLen>
                  </processNewSessionTicket>
                </processHandshakeMessage>
              </processHandshakeRecord>
              <processHandshakeRecord>
                <processHandshakeMessage>
                  <processNewSessionTicket>
                    <ticket_lifetime>0x1449c</ticket_lifetime>
                    <ticket_lifetime>83100</ticket_lifetime>
                    <ticket_age_add>0xb9e9d03d</ticket_age_add>
                    <ticket_age_add>3119108157</ticket_age_add>
                    <m_nonce_size>8</m_nonce_size>
                    <ticketLen>224</ticketLen>
                  </processNewSessionTicket>
                </processHandshakeMessage>
              </processHandshakeRecord>
              <error>The server did not respond in 30000 milliseconds.</error>
              <error>Try increasing the value of your Http.ReadTimeout property.</error>
              <quickCloseHttpConnection ms="265">
                <shutdownChannel ms="265">
                  <info>(bForceClose) socket shutdown..</info>
                  <terminateConnection ms="265">
                    <info>TCP connection cleanly closed by peer.</info>
                    <info>Cleanly terminated TCP connection.</info>
                  </terminateConnection>
                  <info>Clearing TLS client certificates.</info>
                </shutdownChannel>
              </quickCloseHttpConnection>
            </readResponseHeader>
          </fullHttpRequest>
          <statusCode>0</statusCode>
          <success>0</success>
        </a_synchronousRequest>
      </retryAfterLostConnectionDiscovered2>
      <success>False</success>
    </fullRequest>
    <totalTime>Elapsed time: 65172 millisec</totalTime>
    <error>Failed.</error>
  </SynchronousRequest>
</ChilkatLog>
```

Note: I had to stip out few values (cookies and header) as stackoverfllow does nto support post over 30k characters.

can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Note: code is very same as before, nothing has been changed..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I used another chilkat library and it too suddenly stopped working, turns out you need a license and was just working on a free trial.

I coudn't see it in your log but search for the 'UnlockStatus' field:

```
0-> Locked
1-> Free-trial
2-> Unlocked
```

[Docs](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatGlobalRef.html#prop19)

Comment: that's not the issue, though thanks a lot for response..